# Warning revmob session was not started

Tags: ios, xcode, revmob, revmobads

I have integrated the revmob SDK into my Xcode project, but each time I launch the app in the simulator I receive the following message:

```
[39037:4564305] [RevMob] Starting RevMobAds
```

`[39037:4564305] [RevMob] Warning: RevMob session was not started`
`[39037:4564305] [RevMob] Warning: RevMob session was not started`

I have called all the methods in the right places, made sure that the app was set to "testing mode with ads", I have also included the required frameworks and delegates etc. but still it does not work.

How do I solve this any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing ReveMob in a separate thread ?. Using NSThread or NSOperation ? if so, it will timeout even before starting the session.
For example:

```
NSOperation *revMobOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:mediaId andDelegate:self];
}];
```

If this is the case, it will not work. You have must initialize it in the main thread or something like this.

```
NSOperation *revMobOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:mediaId andDelegate:self];
            });
        });

}];
```